# TreeViewItem MouseLeftButtonUp event fired from parent instead of leaf

Tags: wpf, treeview, mouseleftbuttonup

**GOAL**: I am trying to expand my treeview items using a single click. I need to access the `DataContext` of selected node and set the property for expanding/collapsing.

**What I have tried**
I have put `EventSetter` on `TreeViewItem` for `MouseLeftButtonUp` (MLBU) & `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`. However, when a click on a leaf node, in the MLBU handler I get the Header property of sender as Parent and not leaf. The `OriginalSource` is correctly pointing to leaf control. But if I use that I will have to determine all the type of Sources and then get the value out of it.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

XAML for setting the event:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource SomeStyle}">
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"/>
<EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="OnMouseLeftButtonUp"/>
</Style>
```

The treeview items have different datatemplate based on requirement. So in OriginalSource it can be either `Image` or `System.Windows.Documents.Run` (coming for `Label`). Thus, I have to put if-else for each type of control I create. Whereas, my DataContext has top level interface for each item whose property I can set to expand it. So a generic conversion will work.

Comment: If your handlers are for just `TreeViewItem`, the `OriginalSource` should be `TreeViewItem`, and in XAML you should specify the owner for event such as `TreeViewItem.MouseLeftButtonUp` instead of just `MouseLeftButtonUp`. It's a bit hard to get what you mean by this *I will have to determine all the type of Sources* - this can happen if you have one handler for many types of event (and depending on how you set the `Handler` property of EventSetter).

Comment: Thanks for replying @Hopeless. I have updated XAML and other details. Please see. I do not have a generic handler for all types. It is only for `TreeViewItem`

Comment: I've just played around with TreeView. Looks like you can check out the `Source` instead. It should always be the directly interacted `TreeViewItem`. The `sender` is always the top-level TreeViewItem.

Comment: Doesn't this answer suit you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921972/how-to-expand-wpf-treeview-on-single-click-of-item

Comment: @netaholic thanks for replying. I saw this and it looks like this might work. However for one particular treeviewitem for which I am creating a `Label` with `AccessText` property, the OriginalSource is `System.Windows.Documents.Run`. This type is not `Visual` or `Visual3d` because of which `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` throws exception. Do you have any idea about this?